# Shouldn't I follow the OWASP DOM based XSS recommendations no matter where the payload is injected?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xss

I  heard/read at various contexts that DOM based XSS is caused by untrusted client side input and developers need to follow instructions at the OWASP "[DOM based XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)" in order to mitigate it.

My question is: Shouldn't this guide be used irrespective of where the malicious payload is injected (client side which can be from DOM elements like URL, or server side which can be from parameters of immediate previous requests) if you are inserting untrusted data into javascript execution contexts?

Lets keep aside the debate of if it will be called DOM based XSS or not in the later case because I am more interested in knowing if this guide should be applied irrespective of where the payload is coming from (server/client) if you are putting untrusted data in  execution contexts.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you should never put unsanitized user input anywhere on your site. You shouldn't display it, you should't use it to form any queries and you certainly shouldn't include it. Anywhere a user, or a 3rd party of sorts, is inputting any form of data at all, you should sanitize it, and ask yourself:

> How could this be used maliciously?

SQL Injection is one to look out for, and of course XSS is a big one too as you mentioned. XSS is injecting code which is then outputted, and of course SQLi is using input to form a SQL query which could be potentially catastrophic. Of course, there are plenty other attacks which are not injection-based and do not rely on user input, but just sanitize absolutely everything to avoid any problems down the road.

Hope that answers your question, was a bit difficult to understand exactly what you were asking.